# CSS dynamic text alignment depending on the length of the text

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-alignment

Let say i would like to cover the below 2 scenario (the title is dynamic) :
Could that be achieved with CSS only (no JS) for IE8+  ?

Scenario A : short header title to be aligned center relatively to the page width

```
| back button |                 short Title                             |
<-----------------------------------|----------------------------------->
```

Scenario B : very long header title to fill the header content area without being overlayed on the back button

```
|             | Very very very very very very very very very very very  |
| back button | Very very very very very very very very long Title      |
<-----------------------------------|----------------------------------->
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of:

Float the back button left, and the title will wrap naturally.

**HTML**

```
<div>

    <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>

    <h1>Title</h1>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}

a.back {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

<strike>Or this way, same HTML</strike> - Just realised this wont center things properly, unless you have the same 100px padding on the right hand side as well.

```
div {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

a.back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 0;
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

That second one will avoid any wrapping issues and also vertically align the button in the middle.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks Will, it seems the title is not aligned centered relatively to the total width of the page but rather total width - back  button width. Anything i am missing here ? @see http://jsfiddle.net/fhrQX/1/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I'm not sure this is possible. The browser must calculate the center point on a per-line basis so even when it's wrapping text round a float the center point is still in the middle of that actual line. This may be your best compromise: http://jsfiddle.net/will/fhrQX/14/